# Validate Certificate chain with java bouncing castle

Tags: java, validation, certificate, x509certificate

I would like to validate a certificate chain which will be imported into my app. I do not know how.

My coleagues told me, that I have to use Bouncing castle for validation. I saw several examples and still do not have any progress.

I have a `List<X509Certificate>` which contains all certificates which are imported from the UI, and also the `PrivateKey`.

Could you please show me how to validate the certificate chain with Bouncing castle.

Comment: Can you please tell us what do you want to do with the certificates? In most cases the library used (e.g. `HTTPS` or `WS Security`) wil validate the certificate for you.

Comment: I would like to checkif certificate chain is valid or not. Or if the user is not reverse the place of certificates durring importing. In my app certificates are imported through UI as a text. -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE------- and so on. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `java.security.cert.CertificateFactory` to validate your certificate chain.

```
InputStream inStream = ByteArrayInputStream(<data>);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
CertPath cp = cf.generateCertPath(inStream);
List<Certificate> certs = cp.getCertificates();
```

The `certs` now contains the certificate chain. The first entry in `certs` (`certs[0]`) contais the certificate and the following certificates are the chain.

The last entry in `certs` is the root certificate which should be compared to a already existing certificate in your application.

In the case that the certification path could not be built up the above code will throw a `CertificateException`.

Comment: InputStream inStream = ByteArrayInputStream(<data>); This <data> is  it List<X509Certificate> which contains all certificates before validation?

Comment: @user2739823 no the `<data>` is the raw data. So by simply using the `String` entered in the UI you can do byte[] `data = <UIInput>.getBytes()` assuming that `<UIInput>` is the `String` from the UI and there is no special character set used (perhaps check before that the `String` starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------`.

Comment: generateCertificatePath(..) method does not validate the certificate chain! It will create the chain out of whatever certificates you pass to it. There's separate classes (CertPathValidator) for performing the validation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html

Comment: @JuhaPalomäki If you read carefully then you will see that I wrote that you have to validate the certificate chain by yourself then. The getCertPath only returns the certificates but does not validate them...

Answer (score 0):

It is vital that the cert path is actually validated. As mentioned in Uwe Plonus' answer you can create a `CertPath` object by using `CertificateFactory`. The answer is missing the actual validation logic as mentioned by Juha Palomäki.
To validate the `CertPath` additional steps must be performed:

```
// Load the CertPath;
CertificateFactory certificatFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
CertPath certPath = certificatFactory.generateCertPath(certificateInput);

// Load a KeyStore initialized with the root CA certificates to trust
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(trustStoreInput, trustStorePassword);

// Initialize a CertPathValidator
CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");

// Do the validation
certPathValidator.validate(certPath, new PKIXParameters(trustStore));
```

The `validate` method will throw an `CertPathValidatorException` if the path does not validate. Otherwise it returns an instance of `PKIXCertPathValidatorResult` that contains details about the used trust anchor and subject public key. `CertPathValidator` in the default configuration will check that the certificates in the chain are linked, not expired and not revoked.