# Validate certification path with intermediate cert

Tags: java, security

I am trying to validate certification path with domain cert and intermediate cert. The cert do not contain root cert. Is there a way to verify cert path with no root cert provided?

Thanks

---Update----
Method that I have tried on

```
        InputStream trustStoreInput = new FileInputStream(cacertPath);
        String password = password;

        KeyStore anchors = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        anchors.load(trustStoreInput, password.toCharArray());
        X509CertSelector target = new X509CertSelector();

        target.setCertificate(certList.get(1)); <---I have domain cert and intermediate cert
        PKIXBuilderParameters params = new PKIXBuilderParameters(anchors, target);
        CertStoreParameters intermediates = new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList);
        params.addCertStore(CertStore.getInstance("Collection", intermediates));
        CertPathBuilderResult result = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX").build(params);
```

But I got this error

```
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show us what you have tried so far? Also try to use the search function as the question is already answered e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097214/validate-certificate-chain-with-java-bouncing-castle/26098254#26098254).

Comment: Thx for reply, I have tried ur solution, but it throws error <Could not parse certificate> on cf.generateCertPath

Comment: What type of certificate are you using?

Comment: Ssl certificate in PEM format. it contains server cert and intermediate cert.

Comment: Have you included the intermediate certificate in you cacerts? Or does the SSL certificate (I assume X509) the root CA certifiate?

Comment: what do u means by included the intermediate certificate in cacerts? thx for the quick reply :)

Comment: You need a trust anchor in cacerts. That means either that your certificat chains need all certificates up to the root certificate that is in cacerts or at least one of the certificates out of your certificate chain (e.g. the intermediate certificate).